# Cannot run shell script from mounted network share: unidentified developer

Tags: macos, finder, command-line, script, smb

We have a few shared shell scripts on our file server, and would like them to run in Terminal when double-clicked in the Finder.

The share is mounted, and the scripts do run when called by their full path (like `/Volumes/mounted_share/script_name`) in Terminal.

If their name has a `.command` extension, and they are first copied to the local machine, they do run when double-clicked in the Finder.
<sub>(Well, the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute must be removed first. But if not, they can still be run from Finder with right-click > Open)</sub>

But there seems to be no way to have Finder run them directly from the mounted share.

With double-click, they give

> “test.command” can’t be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.
>
> Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the App Store and identified developers.

With right-click + Open, there seems to be more hope:

> “test.command” is from an unidentified developer. Are you sure you want to open it?
>
> Opening “test.command” will always allow it to run on this Mac.

But no! Clicking Open then complains about "access privileges":

> The file “test.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges.
>
> To view or change access privileges, select the file in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

And of course, the "Get Info" suggestion in the message is wrong.

This is on Mojave.

Is there any way to "whitelist" a server share so that Finder can run shared shell scripts?